# get null value for arraylist on next activity

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent, android-activity, arraylist

please help me.i want to pass array list of item name,quantity,amount and rate from make order activity  to next activity confirm order...but on next activity getting null value for that array list what can i do ?

code of make order

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MakeOrder.this,Demo.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("selectedItems",strItemNameAlert);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("selectedRates",strRateAlert);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("selectedQuantity",strQuantityAlert);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("selectedAmount",strAmountAlert);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("selectedId",strItemIdAlert);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Code for confirm order

```
public class ConfirmOrder extends Activity {

     ArrayList<String> resultArrItemname;
     ArrayList<String> resultArrItemrate;
     ArrayList<String> resultArrItemquantity;
     ArrayList<String> resultArrItemamount;
     ArrayList<String> resultArrItemid;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.demo);

        resultArrItemname=new ArrayList<String>();
         resultArrItemrate=new ArrayList<String>();
        resultArrItemquantity=new ArrayList<String>();
         resultArrItemamount=new ArrayList<String>();
          resultArrItemid=new ArrayList<String>();
          Intent intent1=new Intent();
          resultArrItemname = intent1.getStringArrayListExtra("selectedItems");
           resultArrItemrate = intent1.getStringArrayListExtra("selectedRates");
           resultArrItemquantity = intent1.getStringArrayListExtra("selectedQuantity");
           resultArrItemamount = intent1.getStringArrayListExtra("selectedAmount");
           resultArrItemid = intent1.getStringArrayListExtra("selectedId");

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

use

```
 Intent intent1=this.getIntent();
```

instead of

```
 Intent intent1=new Intent();
```

for getting value in next Activity

Answer (score 0):

In **ConfirmOrder** Activity you are creating a new empty intent by doing this.

> Intent intent1=new Intent();

So definitely `intent1.getStringArrayListExtra("selectedItems");`
this will return `null` because nothing is find with selectedItems String inside intent1. You have to call   `getIntent(String uri)` method of `Intent` class to get the values putted in your first Activity.

Use:

```
Intent intent1=this.getIntent();
intent1.getStringArrayListExtra("selectedItems");
```

**Note**:

```
public static Intent   getIntent  (String uri)
```

**This method was deprecated in API level 4.**
Use `parseUri(String, int)` instead.